# can I set the "--disable-console" and "--windows-uac-admin" nuitka options on an already compiled .exe?

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, nuitka

I used nuitka (= a program similar to PyInstaller) to compile my Python code into an exe. When I run it, it doesn't run in administrator mode and also opens the console (since I didn't specify those options). Can I change these options for my already-compiled script or do I really have to re-compile my script?

"python -m nuitka --onefile --disable-console --windows-uac-admin file.exe" obviously didn't work.